# Combining data from csv files in subdirectories with Python

Tags: python

I have a script that walks through subdirectories and combines all data from .csv files into one big .csv.  But I'd like to modify it to create a separate combined .csv for each subdirectory (and ideally name it after the subdirectory).  Nothing that I've tried so far seems to be able to do this.  What am I missing?  My original script is below.

```
datax = []
dirx = 'path/to/folder'
for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(dirx):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            data2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dirs, f), sep=' ', header=None, names=column_names)
            datax.append(data2)
frame = pd.concat(datax)
frame.to_csv('alldata.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

If I move the `frame =` line into the `os.walk` loop it says there is nothing to concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but it might not be the prettiest one:

```
# Your path
dirx = path

# Dictionnary to put all your subdirs concatenates
dict_data = {}

for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):

    # First check if your subdirs is not empty
    if subdirs:

        # For every sudirs you have 
        for i in subdirs:

            # I run a for loop inside of it
            for dirs2, subdirs2, files2 in os.walk(path + "\\"+ i):

                # I then instantiate a list 
                list_data = []
                for j in files2:

                    # I append the data of your different files in this subdir to this list
                    data = pd.read_csv(path + "\\" + i + "\\" + j, sep=' ', header=None, names=column_names)

                    list_data.append(data)

                # Concatenate and store it in the dictionnary, so you have the data compartimented
                dict_data[i] = pd.concat(list_data)

dict_data[frame].to_csv('the/data/from/subdir/wanted', sep=',', index=False)
```

It should give you results like this (testi, testa being my subdirs):

[image]

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Yes, I didn't use your code exactly but I did an os.walk inside another os.walk and that (eventually) got what I needed...thanks so much!